# Strange summation? $\sum _{k=-n}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^k}{x-k}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, summation, special-functions

I'm mainly concerned with the bounds of summation here. I've never personally seen such a summation before, but I came across this summation in "Special Functions" by Andrews Askey Roy on page 11. Can someone explain to me or tell me laconically the name of this type of summation? I can do the remainder of the research
It reminds me of proving a series of a sequence of functions converging uniformly (via Cauchy Condition), but this (of course) involves different bounds of summation. I imagine this is a property of summation; the same type of property used in Cauchy's Condition for a uniformly convergent series of sequence of functions. To be clear:
$$\bigg|\sum_{k=0}^{n} f_{k}(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{m}f_{k}(x)\bigg|$$
$$=\bigg|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}f_{k}(x)\bigg|$$
But, with m=-n+1
$$=\bigg|\sum_{k=-n}^{n}f_{k}(x)\bigg|$$
Am I correct? Isn't this similar?
This was half(probably not half) of a proof that Roy was doing. He was attempting to show that $\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi x)}=\frac{1}{x}+2x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2-n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{x-k}$.
He uses the the integral$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}}{1+t}dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{x-1}}{1+t} dt +\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{1+t}dt$$
In fact, I was able to get myself that the right hand integral (the second integral on the right-hand side) is
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}s^{x+k}}{x+k}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{x+k}$$

Comment: It's just a summation. You plug in $k=-n,-n+1,-n+2,\dots,n+1$ and add them all up.

Comment: @GerryMyerson LOL! That's too reductive and not what I'm looking for. I've found the name of this type of notation. It's called Andre Weil-Eisenstein Summation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have a citation for that nomenclature? I've never seen that term before.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, no problem! https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/8714

Comment: I don't see any use of the phrase, "Weil-Eisenstein summation" in that article. I see a mention of Eisenstein's summation  process, but as a method of dealing with conditionally convergent series. Those are necessarily *infinite* series, so it has nothing to do with the finite sum $\sum_{-n}^{n+1}$ in the title of your question. I don't think there's any good reason to call $$\sum_{-n}^{n+1}$ an Eisenstein summation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Here we go. You need to read the book that I referenced hereinabove by Andrews. Eisenstein had the representation of an infinite series in the form $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}}$. Andre Weil's representation of an infinite series is of the form $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^{n]$. Credit should be given where credit is due, regardless of public, popular consensus.

Comment: @GerryMyerson As for the series I referenced, that was part of a proof, where Andrews used this notation 2/3rds into the proof to show that $$\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi x)}=\frac{1}{x}+2x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2-n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{x-k}$$. After reading further in Andrews, he explains that "Weil's summation" (denoted by the limit representation) is the same as the Eisenstein's summation. Weil himself has called the limit representation, admittedly, the Eisenstein summation, but if Eisenstein didn't use that representation...

Comment: @GerryMyerson Then shouldn't it be the combination of the two (i.e. Weil-Eisenstein)? I mean, both mathematicians made significant contributions to mathematics. It would be a different story if a senior undergraduate mathematician, such as myself, gave it the name "The Dinkins-Eisenstein Summation" if I was the one who gave it that representation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I will admit, though, that I should have been more clear about what I was asking. But, as I have found, there is a name for this type of summation; whether you want to call it $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$ Eisenstein or Weil-Eisenstein $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}$$ is completely up to you; there are no "mathematical authorities".

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think Eisenstein called that summation "The Eisenstein Summation". If he did, then he was quite full of himself lol!

Comment: The fact remains, that what you are discussing in these comments is an *infinite* summation, whereas what you have in the title of the question is a *finite* summation, and these are very, very different things. What's in the title is just a normal everyday ordinary summation, and no one would attribute that kind of summation to Weil, Eisenstein, or Weil-Eisenstein. As for the infinite sums, I doubt that Eisenstein was the first ever to write $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, and I'm certain Weil wasn't the first to define such a summation (continued)

Comment: (continued) as meaning $\lim{n\to\infty}\sum_{-n}^n$. That must go back much earlier than the 1920s when Weil started producing mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*
Write
$$
T_n := \sum_{k=-n}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^k}{x-k}
$$
then for $0 < m < n$ we have
$$
T_n-T_m = \sum_{k=-n}^{-m-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{x-k} + \sum_{k=m+2}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^k}{x-k}
$$
Then use the usual Cauchy condition for sequences on the sequence $\{T_n\}$.